# How to read excel as a pyspark dataframe

Tags: azure, pyspark, azure-databricks, azure-authentication, azure-data-lake-gen2

I am able to read all the files and formats like csv, parquet, delta from adls2 account with oauth2 cred.

However when I am trying to read excel file like below,

```
df = spark.read.format("com.crealytics.spark.excel") \
.option("header", "true") \
.option("inferSchema", "true") \
.option("dataAddress", "'excel sheet name'!A1") \
.load(filepath)
```

I am getting below error

> Failure to initialize configurationInvalid configuration value detected for fs.azure.account.key

Note: I have installed external library "com.crealytics:spark-excel_2.11:0.12.2" to read excel as a dataframe.

Can anyone help me with error here?

Comment: Can you share the configs ?

Comment: Could you please be more specific on what config I need to share?

Comment: oauth2  from SparkConfig

Answer (score 0):

Try to use in configs as:  `"fs.azure.account.oauth2.client.secret": "<key-name>"`,

And different versions have different set of parameters, so try use the latest release: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.crealytics/spark-excel_2.12/0.13.7